# Clear Access Form fields for Insert

Tags: database, ms-access

I have done doing form in access for inserting records.
 
When open that form the field inside it appear filled with previous record l want them to be empty for allowing the user fill the filed, what should I do please!

Comment: Please provide more information about your solution, so we can help you better.

Comment: Your picture shows record #1, not a new record.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to go to a new record just use the following in the load event

```
private sub yourformname_load()
docmd.gotorecord acdataform,"yourformname", acNewRec
'or
'docmd.gotorecord ,, acNewRec
```

To keep them from viewing previous records

```
me.navigationbuttons = false
```

To allow them to view just not edit previous records

```
me.allowedits = false
```

If you want to go to another new record when they click the ok button just put the same `docmd...` in the Click event of your button.